# How to make SSO among SpringBoot apps running on same Tomcat under different context?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

How can one build/configure single authentication for apps built by SpringBoot and running under different contexts in Tomcat? It seems to me very common scenario, we have multiple apps that we maintain  separately but they have to share the same login, so user can switch among them without authenticate to each one with the same credentials. Any idea how to make it done easily?